# Conditionally finding dependencies of shared library in CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, dependencies, shared-libraries

In Linux I have a shared library `somelib.so`, which could be optionally compiled against several other shared libs, say, `dep1` and `dep2`. Now I'm writing a client application which uses `somelib`, but I don't now in advance if `somelib` was compiled with `dep1` and `dep2` or not until I get a linker error.

Is there a way to find this out using CMake? I need something like

```
IF somelib DEPEND ON dep1 THEN...
```

Comment: You can use `try_compile()` to build a test application that uses `somelib.so` and see if it builds without any extra `libs`.  You may consider creating a config file when building `somelib.so` that can be imported into new projects so that link dependencies are known when using the library.

Answer (score 2):

> ... client application which uses somelib, but I don't now in advance
>   if somelib was compiled with dep1 and dep2 ... I need something like
>
> ```
> IF somelib DEPEND ON dep1 THEN...
> ```

On Linux I believe the way to solve it is using LD linker options `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` and `-Wl,--as-needed`.

Always include `-ldep1` and `-ldep2` as library options. Then use `-Wl,--as-needed` to exclude the libraries if unneeded.

If I recall correctly, this trick dates back 20 or 30 years or so for the math library `-lm`. Sometimes math symbols were included in `glibc` and other times they were included in `-lm`. So you always linked against `-lm` and allowed the linker to discard the `-lm` library with `-Wl,--as-needed`.

In fact the [`ld(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) says to push and pop state when using the trick:

> One target for this option are specifications for pkg-config.
>   When used with the --libs option all possibly needed libraries
>   are listed and then possibly linked with all the time.  It is
>   better to return something as follows:
>
> ```
>  -Wl,--push-state,--as-needed -libone -libtwo -Wl,--pop-state
> ```

`-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` is an option to keep you from re-exporting symbols from `-ldep1` and `-ldep2`. If the libraries are not used then you should not need `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`.

I believe the two CMake settings for a static library and shared object when building `somelib.so` are:

```
set(OUR_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL -Wl,--as-needed -ldep1 -ldep2")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OUR_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OUR_LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

Also see [`ld(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), [CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) and [CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html) in the CMake docs. You might also be interested in [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) if you are building executables.